# Does JFreeChart have support for three dimensional charts

Tags: java, jfreechart

As Every one knows `JFreeChart` supports 2-D (X,Y) charts, but I have a program that needs 3-D (X,Y,Z), 4-D (X,Y,Z,E) … up to six dimensions. For example,
my input data looks like this for 2D (X,Y):

```
(0.611787,2.304051)       
(1.636265 ,2.261579)       
(1.073176 ,1.188980)
```

If I have 3D (X,Y,Z), it looks like this:

```
(0.142197 ,1.440918 ,0.217366)       
(0.149352 ,0.748124 ,3.214357)       
(0.536232 ,0.107004 ,4.198831)
```

If I have four columns, it means 4-D, and may increase to 6-D. I need some help and suggestions if `JFreeChart` supports 3-D. If not, is there any other software similar to `JfreeChart` that can be integrated with Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) includes the `XYZDataset` interface, and implementing classes are suitable for three dimensional data. It's up to your program to determine how best to display the third dimension. For example, `XYBlockRenderer` uses a `PaintScale`, while other schemes use `XYZToolTipGenerator` or `XYZURLGenerator`. AFAIK, higher dimensions are not supported.

Comment: I will try that..Thanks for sugegstions

Answer (score 1):

I did, eventually, end up writing JFreeChart3D...but it is not free, so I called it [Orson Charts](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/index.html).  It has quite a similar style to JFreeChart (plots, datasets, renderers) and even does all the rendering via Graphics2D (so you can still export to JPG, PNG, SVG, PDF and other formats with existing converters).

[image: Sample screenshot]

Comment: Orson Charts now has an additional (open source) license option: the GNU GPLv3.